# SharePoint Profile Picture access rights

Tags: permissions, picture

After setting user profile pictures (and user information pictures) for all our SharePoint users (images are kept in a list in one of the site collections), we configured user profiles so that users can update their picture at any moment.

The problem is, when the user uploads a picture, it is automatically placed in their Shared Pictures library, but this library does not have sufficient permissions set for other users. I checked the "Permissions for this picture library" of the Shared Pictures and it inherits the rights from MySite, which are: full control for the user and limited access for our System Account.

I checked the Default Reader Site Group setting for the My Site in Central Admin: 'NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users' (this setting was there when all My Sites were created).

I also checked the default privacy settings of the Picture property and it is set to Everyone, user can override - no, replicable - checked, edit settings: allow users to edit.
The result is, all pictures uploaded personally by users appear as broken links because no other user has access to see it.

What are we missing?

Comment: Which sharepoint version you are using? In my sp2013 environment, MySiteHost is setup with default settings, all users' profile pictures is uploaded to same public library.

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens if there is a change of url for the mysite. A resolution for this mentioned on this link : [How to fix broken images after mySite URL change in SharePoint 2010?](http://www.normanbauer.com/2012/01/27/how-to-fix-broken-images-after-mysite-url-change-in-sharepoint-2010/)

If this is not the case , then there is a hotfix for the same as discussed on MSDN forums over here: [Profile Pictures showing as broken images](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/f489dac8-2d16-4369-916f-2ffea556c8a2/)

This can solve the issue.

Lastly , try running the User Profile Full Synchronization Service once again and see if that works.